# Iterating an array of nodes, each of which can have children

Tags: c#, performance, stack, iteration

I've written some C# code to iterate through a `Node[]`, listing all of its nodes in order (i.e. child elements are listed immediately after the parent).

Each `Node` is defined as follows,

```csharp
class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; } = new List<Node>();
    
    public bool HasChildren => Children.Count > 0;
    
    public Node(int n)
    {
        Name = $"Node #{n}";
    }
    
    public Node AddChild(Node n)
    {
        Children.Add(n);
        return this;
    }
    
    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

The collection of nodes to be iterated would be,

```csharp
var nodes = new Node[]
{
    new Node(1),
    new Node(2),
    new Node(3)
        .AddChild(new Node(4))
        .AddChild(new Node(5))
        .AddChild(new Node(6)
            .AddChild(new Node(7)))
        .AddChild(new Node(8)
            .AddChild(new Node(9))
            .AddChild(new Node(10)))
};
```

...and output for the above would be 10 lines of "Node #", each followed by the number passed to the constructor of each (i.e. 1 to 10, in ascending order).

The code I've written to perfom the aforementioned task is,

```csharp
var stack = new Stack<(Node[], int)>();

var i = 0;

while (i < nodes.Length)
{
    WriteLine($"{nodes[i]}");

    if (nodes[i].HasChildren)
    {
        // Stores away the current Node[] and the next index, to return to it once all children are iterated though.
        stack.Push((nodes, i + 1));
        
        // Makes the child Node[] the iteration target.
        nodes = nodes[i].Children.ToArray();

        // Resets the index to iterate all the children.
        i = 0;

        continue;
    }

    // If the current node is the last in the targeted Node[], and there are parent Node[]s from which this Node[] was switched to in the stack.
    if (i == nodes.Length - 1 && stack.Count > 0)
    {
        // Pop the stack until the popped Node[] isn't the last element, and assign it to the array being iterated.

        var (_target, _i) = stack.Pop();

        while (stack.Count > 0 && _i >= _target.Length)
        {
            (_target, _i) = stack.Pop();
        }

        nodes = _target;
        i = _i;

        continue;
    }

    ++i;
}
```

Any criticism of my algorithm? Does it work for `Node[]`s of any depth (level of child-ception ;)? Ways in which it can be optimized?

`(T1, T2)` is a [`ValueTuple`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct).

Comment: You don't want to write a recursive function for it?

Comment: @EBrown a recursive function is simpler to understand and more elegant, but isn't the safest way as I understand. A deep enough `Node[]` would cause a stack overflow, wouldn't it?

Comment: *Eventually*, yes. But you can do things like tail-call recursion (google that, I'm on mobile unfortunately) which will *not* have such an effect.

Comment: @EBrown thanks, I shall look into that. However for the purpose of this question, let's assume that I don't want to go recursive :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Collection initializer

You can improve and simplify your code by first tuning the `Node`.

- make it `IEnumerable<T>` and consequently remove the `Children` and `HasChildren` properties because now we can use LINQ's `Any`
- let the `Name` property take care of the formatting and keep the `value` clean in a dedicated field
- replace `AddChild` with the `Add` method to be able to use collection initializer
- replace the array with a root node

Example:

```
public class Node<T> : IEnumerable<Node<T>>
{
    private readonly T _value;

    private readonly List<Node<T>> _children = new List<Node<T>>();

    public Node(T value) => _value = value;

    public T Value => _value;

    public string Name => $"Node #{_value}";

    public void Add(Node<T> node) => _children.Add(node);

    public override string ToString() => Name;

    public IEnumerator<Node<T>> GetEnumerator() => _children.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

---

## Enumerator

Now you can improve the algorithm by using the `Enumerator`. There is no need for any indexes or tuples. What you need to do is to `GetEnumerator` from each node and `MoveNext` on it until it is now longer possible to continue or continue from a sub node if it contains `Any`.

The enumerator will keep the current state allowing you to continue iterating on child nodes and resume from the parent node later that's why you need to re-push the current node back to the stack.

An extension for the `Node<T>` could look like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Node<T>> Flatten<T>(this Node<T> root)
{
    var stack = new Stack<IEnumerator<Node<T>>>();
    stack.Push(root.GetEnumerator()); // start with the root node

    yield return root; // return the root node
    
    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var node = stack.Pop();
        while (node.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return node.Current;
            if (node.Current.Any())
            {
                stack.Push(node); // re-add the node to continue later
                stack.Push(node.Current.GetEnumerator()); // continue from here now
                break; // we'll continue from "node" later, when node.Current is enumerated
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Example

You can now create nodes like arrays without confusing parenthesess when adding subnodes:

```
var nodes = new Node<int>(0)
{
    new Node<int>(1),
    new Node<int>(2),
    new Node<int>(3)
    {
        new Node<int>(4),
        new Node<int>(5)
        {
            new Node<int>(6)
            {
                new Node<int>(7)
            },
            new Node<int>(8)
            {
                new Node<int>(9),
                new Node<int>(10)
            },
            new Node<int>(11)
        }
    },
    new Node<int>(12)
};
```

after flattening it

```
nodes.Flatten().Select(n => n.Name).Dump();
```

you'll get:

> ```
> Node #0 
> Node #1 
> Node #2 
> Node #3 
> Node #4 
> Node #5 
> Node #6 
> Node #7 
> Node #8 
> Node #9 
> Node #10 
> Node #11 
> Node #12
> ```

Answer (score 1):

A typical iterative preorder traversal works like this:

Create a stack, push the root to the stack. While the stack is not empty, process the top element and push its children right-to-left to the stack.

So I suggest the following function to traverse the nodes:

```
static void IterateNodes(Node[] nodes)
{
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<Node>();
        stack.Push(node);
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            Node current = stack.Pop();
            Console.WriteLine(current);
            var childrenRightToLeft = current.Children.AsEnumerable().Reverse();
            foreach (var child in childrenRightToLeft)
            {
                stack.Push(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note I don't have C#7 available, so I used some things like `Console.WriteLine` that you are free to change anyway you like.